# AdMob displays different Ads with same ID on iOS

Tags: ios, admob

I’ve made a game with libgdx, and imported Google Ads SDK to add ads.
I downloaded a sample project to see how I should have imported Interstital.
But soon I found out that the interstial shown in my app were very different from the one shown in the sample project, but I don’t know why 
Does somebody knows what this could be all about?

**Sample project interstitial:**

[image]

**My game interstitial:**

[image]

EDIT: the two projects use the same AdMob account and Ad ID

Comment: Hi, I'm very much willing to help you out here, as I am well experienced with AdMob iOS. What do you mean by ```weirdly```? Both interstitial are fine.

Comment: Yeah, you right, weirdly it’s not the right term. I’m editing the question

Comment: @Glenn What I mean is that, in the sample project I get ads like the one shown above: video promoting apps on the AppStore, which can not be closed for the first 5 seconds (so generating higher revenue and, according to me, much more appealing to users), instead the ads running in my application are simply rich text which can be closed instantly and, always according to me, less appealing. So the point is that I cannot understand why this happens, since they both run on my phone and they both uses the same Interstitial ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't fully control what you want the users to see in your **Interstitial** ad. And you have to be mindful of the Google AdMob's best practices and policies too.

If you want a custom layout, you can use **Native Ads Advanced (Unified)** https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/native-unified

And if you ONLY want a video rewarded ad, there's another format of ad available:

**Rewarded Video Ads** https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rewarded-video

I hope this helps.

EDIT: OP knows the info above, apparently. What OP wanted to know is the reason why the two projects have different ad content.

There should be multiple reasons why you experienced that.

1. Bundle Ids of the apps.
2. Either of the two projects has set test device id (or simulator id) to generate test ad, and the other one has not, thus giving you different ads.

Some AdMob's FAQs:

1. Do I have to choose which ads to show in my app?

> No. AdMob automatically serves ads to your apps from the AdMob Network
>   and third-party networks of your choosing. These ads can be targeted
>   to your app content and audience.
>
> If you do want control over what appears in your app, you can block
>   ads from certain advertisers and categories from being shown in your
>   app.

2. Who decides which ads to show in my app?

> AdMob uses an ad auction to automatically select the ads that will
>   appear on your pages from all the available ad sources. Generally, the
>   highest performing ads will be shown in your app.
>
> If you do want control over what appears in your app, you can block
>   ads from certain advertisers and categories from being shown in your
>   app.

To know more, read: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7356092?hl=en

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but I don’t understand why app#1 gets always the same type of ad, and app#2 gets always another one, that’s it

Comment: Thank you, you have been very kind :)

Comment: No problem. :) Remember to select an answer for your every questions if there's any, to close it :D

Comment: @GlennPosadas How many banner-ads we can show in our app, Is there any limit for it? Also should we use unique adUnitId for each banner ads ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1 per screen ideally. No, you may use 1 banner Id I guess per screen, but I think it'd be better if you use one Id as well per screen.